# Google Apps Script, import ics files

Tags: google-apps-script, import, calendar

How can I import ics files by using google apps script?
In my case i would like to import multiple ics files, from Gdrive or from local pc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea how to read ics files in GAS